# how to add blazor in an existing ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have worked on a Blazor server app with CRUD operations but I am trying to work on CRUD operations by adding Blazor as view (frontend) to an existing ASP.NET MVC application, but I am unable to do so.

Please help me find a solution for this.

Thanks!

In ASP.NET MVC, the razor view can bind the value to its model, so I was trying to understand how do we do that in Blazor and how we can add view to the particular controller view using Blazor and perform CRUD operations and I am not getting how to do that in existing ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: This article shows how to add Blazor to an existing MVC application - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321697/Building-a-Blazor-Server-Application-from-the-Web.  On how to do CRUD in a Blazor/MVC setting there are plenty of online tutorials.  Split your code out.  The core application and Infrastructure code are the same.  The views and the UI are different.